# dojox.enhancedGrid get Selected Row

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

How can I get the Selected Row Object of dojox.enhancedGrid ?
I am using selectionMode: 'single'
e.g. with Radio Buttons.

`dijit.byId("gridViewWidget").selection.selectedIndex`
Returns the rowIndex.
But how to get the rowObject of that Index ?
I can get the `rowNode()`But What I need is value of the id column of that Row.

Its possible to travarse the HTML DOM returned by `rowNode()` But Is there any straight forward way ?

I am currently using `dijit.byId("gridViewWidget").store._dataArray[i]` and passing the returned index. Though This works it seems _dataArray is a private property.
So Is it safe to use ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm new to dojo myself, but this should be useful if not entirely correct. First of all, `dojox.grid.enhancedGrid` is built on top of `dojox.grid.DataGrid`, so check out the documentation here:

[**dojox.grid.DataGrid Documentation**](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/grid/DataGrid.html#getting-a-value-from-a-row-knowing-the-row-index)

- `grid.getItem(idx)` returns the store 'item' at the given index
- `grid.selection.getSelected()` returns an array of the selected items

You should be able to use either of these to get the item you want.

Comment: Hmm I've tried But there is no such method named `getItem(idx)` or `getSelected()` on the selection object.
my be the selection object is different for dataGrid and enhanced grid.

Comment: Hm, that could be. Like i said, im no expert... and the documentation is also misleading... best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Using declarative markup, you could do something like (from memory, may need tweaking to be functional):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatThisColumn(rowIndex, rowObject) {
    if (rowObject == null) return;
    field = rowObject.i.fieldName;
    return field;
}
</script>
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" id="store" jsid="jsonStore" url="test.json"></div>
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid" id="gridNode" jsid="grid" store="store">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th get="formatThisColumn">A Computed Column</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Note the 'formatThisColumn' function: this gets called at least once per row in the datagrid, and gets passed the index of the row (within the JSON items) and a object that contains the 'current' item (using the 'i' index). This gives you the original values from the JSON response while the datagrid is being rendered.